# How to write joins using Dynamic AX source component in SSIS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

```
SELECT * FROM %1  JOIN %2  ON %1.GROUPID==%2.GROUPID
```

it fails with  error messages

> [Dynamics AX Source [8]] Error: Attempt to read message string for 0xc02090f5 failed with error 0xc02090f2. Make sure all message related files are registered.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Dynamics AX Source returned error code 0xC02090F5.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

i tried two table joins and multiple table joins in AX source component, really have not idea why throwing errors. Any ideas with  syntax would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT * FROM %1 JOIN %2 WHERE %2.GROUPID == %1.GROUPID

Note that you are not able to select columns from the second table(%2 table) due to the limitation of the component.Which means the AX source component cannot return columns from multiple tables. I guess , the way to join is to create multiple AX source component  join together by the "merge join component".